# How to compile latest pulseaudio with webrtc in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio

sound  device:

```
arecord -l
    **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
      Subdevices: 0/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 2: ALC892 Alt Analog [ALC892 Alt Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I did

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio
cd pulseaudio 
./configure --prefix=/usr     \
        --sysconfdir=/etc    \
        --localstatedir=/var \
        --disable-bluez4     \
        --disable-rpath      &&
make
```

I got this error: "configure: error: *** sys/capability.h not found.  Use --without-caps to disable capabilities support."

so added --without-caps

```
./configure --prefix=/usr     \
    --sysconfdir=/etc    \
    --localstatedir=/var \
    --disable-bluez4     \
    --disable-rpath   
    --without-caps   &&
make
```

But I got another error "configure: error: Package requirements ( sndfile >= 1.0.20 ) were not met"

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. Just run

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev libcap-dev
```

re-run `./configure`, and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Hugeblank, also `sudo apt-get install libcap-dev`solved them

Comment: I recommend to install `libspeexdsp-dev` too